# Stuck in "while" Loop, while trying to search for specific text

Tags: python, list, text

I have a file looking something like this

```
/begin FUNCTION

wrapper_d
""
  **this block may be or may not contain any variable name**
/end FUNCTION

/begin FUNCTION


wrapper_hc
""
/begin def_string
  Var1,Var2,Var3 ....
/end def_string
/begin in_measurment
 ......
/begin out_measurment
 varX,varY,varZ ....
/end out_measurment
```

**I want to extract Var1,2,3 and varX,Y,Z to a list,from wrapper_d and wrapper_hc blocks.I use this for now :**

```
input_file = open(path_to_a2l,'r')
for line in input_file:
 if "wrapper_d" in line:
        while "/begin def_string" not in line:
            try:
                next_line = next(input_file)
                
                if "/begin def_string" in next_line:
                    while "/end def_string" not in next_line:
                        new_line = next(input_file)
                        if "/end def_string" in new_line:
                            break
                        listName.extend(new_line.split())
                    break
            except StopIteration as e :
                print (e)
                break
```

I have 4 similar blocks, one for each wrapper(_d and _hc) and one for each delimitator(begin/end def_string and begin/end_measurement).
My problem is, that in this case wrapper_d has nothing inside it(though, it may have with other files), and such, it will go all the way down to wrapper.hc and find "def_string" there.
How can i make the "if" loop stop before reaching the "wrapper_hc" block ?

I hope i made myself clear

Comment: I can't answer your question but I can think of a workaround using for-loop instead. Interested?

Comment: Go ahead, why not

Answer (score 1):

```
files = '''/begin FUNCTION

wrapper_d
""
  **this block may be or may not contain any variable name**
/end FUNCTION

/begin FUNCTION


wrapper_hc
""
/begin def_string
  Var1,Var2,Var3 ....
/end def_string
/begin in_measurment
 ......
/begin out_measurment
 varX,varY,varZ ....
/end out_measurement'''
print(files)

eachline = files.split('\n')

limit = []
for line in range(len(eachline)):
    if eachline[line] == 'wrapper_d':
        limit.append(line+1)
    if eachline[line] == 'wrapper_hc':
        limit.append(line)

for i in range(limit[0], limit[1]):
    if ',' in eachline[i]:
        print(i, eachline[i])

for j in range(limit[1]+1, len(eachline)):
    if ',' in eachline[j]:
        print(j, eachline[j])
```

The `for i` and `for j` parts are of course adjustable to your need.

`limit` always has 2 elements, `limit[0]` is the line directly after `wrapper_d` and `limit[1]` is the line where `wrapper_hc` is. `i` goes between one line after `wrapper_d` and one line before `wrapper_hc`, while `j` goes between one line after `wrapper_hc` and the last line.